# Guttenberg search link Customization issue

Tags: wordpress, block, wordpress-gutenberg, wordpress-block-theme

I've search the pages by slug in guttenberg button link to attach the page link in button but they have show specific post type.
I want to search the pages in link search box in guttenberg they have show only custom post type given in screenshot below. i want to show the pages only search box.

[image]